# Dataset.WriteXml - In XML file created regarding to an XSD, nodes does not appear nested

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, dataset

I have a XSD file and I load it into a Dataset. Apparently, relationships between nested elements in XSD established in Dataset just fine, but when it comes to generate XML file regarding the XSD, nodes appear all in same level.

It should look as following:

```
DBMS  
    DATABASE  
            TABLE
```

I checked dataset in debug mode, all datarelations are existed and Nested properties are set true.

XSD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>Created with EditiX (http://www.editix.com) at Thu Oct 31 21:35:29 EET 2013</xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="dbms">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name ="database" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs ="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>              
                          <xs:element name ="table" minOccurs ="0" maxOccurs ="unbounded">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:attribute name="name"></xs:attribute>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:attribute name ="name"></xs:attribute>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name ="name"></xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

XML File:

```
<MetaDataManagement>
  <dbms name="mssql" />
  <database name="master" />
  <database name="tempdb" />
  <database name="model" />
  <database name="msdb" />
  <database name="ReportServer" />
  <database name="ReportServerTempDB" />
  <database name="kutuphane" />
  <table name="spt_fallback_db" />
  <table name="spt_fallback_dev" />
  <table name="spt_fallback_usg" />
  <table name="spt_values" />
  <table name="spt_monitor" />
  <table name="MSreplication_options" />
  <table name="sysmail_profile" />
  <table name="syscollector_config_store_internal" />
  <table name="sysutility_ucp_policy_check_conditions" />
  <table name="sysutility_ucp_supported_object_types_internal" />
  <table name="sysutility_ucp_policy_target_conditions" />
  <table name="sysutility_ucp_policy_violations" />
  <table name="sysutility_ucp_managed_instances_internal" />
  <table name="sysmail_principalprofile" />
  <table name="syscollector_config_store" />
  <table name="sysutility_ucp_mi_health_internal" />
  <table name="sysmaintplan_subplans" />
  <table name="syspolicy_policy_category_subscriptions" />
  <table name="sysdac_instances_internal" />


.....
</MetaDataManagement>
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

The `DataSet` class is meant to be an in-memory representation of data from a relational database. It is not meant to be a general-purpose XML processing class.

As it happens, you have not even created a standard parent-child-grandchild model with your schema. Where are the foreign keys? Where are the primary keys?